# dwa_local_planner unable to make narrow U turn

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
things work perfectly when the robot goes straight, turning, or making wide U turns. However, I'm facing an issue that the robot stuck at certain location when its trying to make narrow U turn as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVbUG0zQvYA&feature=youtu.be).
Below is my dwa_local_planner parameters.

```
planner_frequency: 0.25
controller_frequency: 10.0
DWAPlannerROS:
   max_trans_vel: 0.25
   min_trans_vel: 0.05
   max_vel_x: 0.25
   min_vel_x: -0.05
   max_rot_vel: 0.6
   min_rot_vel: 0.2
   acc_lim_x: 2.5
   acc_lim_theta: 6.0
   occdist_scale: 0.01
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
   oscillation_reset_angle: 0.2
   path_distance_bias: 60
   sim_time: 2.0
   sim_granularity: 0.1
   angular_sim_granularity: 0.1
   vx_samples: 3
   vy_samples: 1  # zero for a differential drive robot
   vtheta_samples: 20
   dwa: true
```

Did anyone face the same issue i'm facing? If so, can you explain what is happening?

Thanks a lot, Will

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246417/dwa_local_planner-unable-to-make-narrow-u-turn/) by [piliwilliam](https://answers.ros.org/users/24159/piliwilliam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

first, the narrow U turn is not really narrow. I think that's caused by your costmap inflation layer's improper setting.
from video, the costmap inflation is overlaped between the U turn. so this can affect the planner's result.
you can try to change the parameter, and adjust the proper parameters to make your car go through.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0